# Cygwin error install sshd

Tags: openssl, cygwin, openssh, sshd

I am currently trying to install sshd via cygwin and getting the following error

```
$ ssh-host-config -y
/usr/share/csih/cygwin-service-installation-helper.sh: line 694: [: -gt: unary o  perator expected
/usr/share/csih/cygwin-service-installation-helper.sh: line 718: test: -gt: unar  y operator    expected
*** ERROR:  is using csih-0.9.7.
*** ERROR: csih-0.9.7 requires WinNT or above.
*** ERROR: The current operating system is:
*** ERROR: unknown.
```

Comment: Have you tried to follow instruction like [these](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/preinstall_req_cygwin_ssh.htm)

Comment: @MichaelPetch that doesn't work. I tried uninstalling and installing the openssh and got an error. Found here http://pastie.org/9558625

Comment: Oddball question but do you have gzip installed in your cygwin environment?